# Python Function with multiple arugements, some known, some unknown

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, arguments

I've tried to search for the answer to this around the web, and I'm not sure if I'm phrasing it properly or not, but I can't seem to find my answer. What I'd like to do is write a function that does some work with arguments in which some are of known values (input/output files) but some are unknown in number (jinja value passing). I understand the idea of *args, but I don't think that will work in this case.

Here's what I'd like to work:

```
from jinja2 import Template

def myTemplate(inputFile, outputFile *args):
    with open(inputFile, 'r') as r:
        render = Template(r.read())
   
    outputFile = render.render(*args)
```

The last line of this could be one dictionary, two or three single variables, etc. I do this several times in a script (without a dedicated function), but it's this last part that is keeping me from writing it as a single function and then just calling it. Feels like sloppy coding to not wrap a function around this because, other than this last line, the code is identical.

Comment: Strive to write functions that take file-like objects as arguments, not file names. This makes your function more flexible and easier to test. Let the caller worry about opening a file with a given name if necessary.

Comment: More on-topic, use `*args` and/or `**kwargs` to accept arguments you don't care about aside from passing them on to another function that *does* are about them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solution was simply using **kwargs correctly...

```
from jinja2 import Template

def myTemplate(inputFile, outputFile **kwargs):
    with open(inputFile, 'r') as r:
        render = Template(r.read())
   
    outputFile = render.render(**kwargs)
```

with this you can pass as many variables to the render engine of jinja as you'd like.